# jquery: slide two div with zoom in/out effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I have two < div> `leftdiv` and `rightdiv` both with 50% width.

`leftdiv` slides to left and it's width increases to look like a zoom in effect.

same happens to `rightdiv`.

here is my code:

`css`

```
.leftdiv {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0px;
width:50%;
-webkit-transition:all 2.0s ease;
-moz-transition:all 2.0s ease;
-o-transition:all 2.0s ease;
transition:all 2.0s ease;
}
.rightdiv {
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0px;
width:50%;
-webkit-transition:all 2.0s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 2.0s ease;
  -o-transition:all 2.0s ease;
  transition:all 2.0s ease;
}
```

`JQUERY`

```
jQuery('.leftdiv').stop().animate({ right: '-90%' });
$('.leftdiv').css('width','80%');
jQuery('.rightdiv').stop().animate({ left: '-90%' });
$('.rightdiv').css('width','80%');
```

This code slides out `leftdiv` to left and `rightdiv` to right as i want but before sliding out in slides in a bit and then it slides out.

may be it's due to increase in width.

how can i correct that. Can i add a timing or `delay` before increasing width to correct it.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this, JQuery `.animate()` function also take another parameter which is the end animation callback. Do you want to increase width right after the `right : '-90%'` is finished ?

Comment: i want to increase width along with the `right:'-90%` . so that it looks like a zoom in effect. Am i doing it wrong..??

Comment: Okay, so you can stack animation like this : `JQuery('.leftdiv').stop().animate({ right : '-90%' }).animate({ width : '80%' });`.

Comment: with this it's width is increasing after `right:'90%'`.

Comment: Oh sorry, you can also stack propreties you want to animate inside one single animation like this : `.animate({ right : '-90%', widh : '80%' });`. Tell us if it worked.

Comment: yes it did. thanks a lot. why don't you put it in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery animation properties can stack each other (seperated by a comma) in one single call of the method like below :

```
jQuery('.leftdiv').stop().animate({ 
    left: '-90%',
    width : '80%'
});

jQuery('.rightdiv').stop().animate({ 
    right: '-90%',
    width : '80%'
});
```

Comment: jQuery('.leftdiv').stop().animate({ 
    left: '-90%',
    width : '80%'
});

jQuery('.rightdiv').stop().animate({ 
    right: '-90%',
    width : '80%'
});